# Connecting to target device in codesys

Tags: gateway, plc, codesys

I want to connect my PLC with Codesys. When i scan for the network in communication settings, the gateway is green but it does not find any device.

When I connect the same PLC with my laptop it works but when i try to connect with the monitor near the PLC Codesys does not find the device.

I also have the SoftPLC which is on, but still no response.

May I know what may be the reason?

Comment: Don't know if this will help in your case, but I use Modicon controllers, and they require a driver be installed and running on my machine for me to be able to connect to them. Usually when I can't connect, it's because of that for me. Manually starting the driver (form Services), or installing it if missing helps me. Your case will probably be different though...

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but I've had a similar problem connecting through a local network with a router.  I solved it by enabling network discovery in Windows settings on my PC.  If you are on a secure network, try to disable the firewall to test as well.

Comment: I think there is a way to connect directly to a PLC without having to run the Scan if you have the plc IP (I imagine you have already tested the network with a ping in cmd).  unfortunately I can't test this right now, but you can look it up in codesys settings

Comment: @dwpessoa tried the way you suggested it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly fill in the IP-address of the PLC. This way you don't need to use 'scan network' to find the PLC first.

Comment: Yes, at end this was the only option which was left and i could able to connect by entering the IP address of the PLC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the ip of your computer and the ip of the device you are connected to must be the same. For example,
192.168.2.20 (your pc)
192.168.2.10 (device)

You can do this from the network connections.

Then in the connection section, instead of localhost, you must type the ip of the device. If you are sure of your cable connection and your gateway is working correctly, you can connect without any problems.